# PHP MYSQL query returns null with Ajax data, but not hardcoded data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have the following PHP script:

```
include("dbconnecti.php");
$cropId = $_POST['cropId'];
//echo 'the id is: ' . $cropId;

$query = "SELECT W.*,FI.*, PN.*, CONCAT(FI.fName, ' ', FI.lname) AS farmer  
          FROM `wantToSell` AS W, `produceName` AS PN, `farmerInfo` AS FI 
          WHERE W.farmerId = FI.farmerId AND W.produceId = PN.produceId AND W.produceId = '" . $cropId ."'";

$result = $dbconnect->query($query); 
if($result){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $allRows[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($allRows);
 }
 else{
   echo json_encode($dbconnect -> error);
   die;
 }
}
```

And JQuery script:

```
function cropDescrip(clicked_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url : "../php/cropdescrip.php",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : 'JSON',
    cache : false,
    data : {cropId : clicked_id},
    success : function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    } //end success
  }); //end ajax
} //end cropDescrip
```

If I replace `$_POST[cropId]` with a actual value (e.g. tmt001) the query statement returns a valid result. But when I pass a value to `$_POST[cropId]` via a jQuery Ajax call, the SQL query returns an empty set.

The `echo` statement shows that the value is being passed to the PHP script.

What is happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the value of $_POST["cropId"] then? Also show us the script you used to submit!

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string($cropId) in query statement, may be better.

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy ... Updated my question

Comment: Try changing the variable clicked_id to clickedId, which will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be best to change your code to use a prepared statement.  It might solve your problem as well as removing your sql injection risk.  Something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT W.*,FI.*, PN.*, 
      CONCAT(FI.fName, ' ', FI.lname) AS farmer  
      FROM `wantToSell` AS W, `produceName` AS PN, `farmerInfo` AS FI 
      WHERE W.farmerId = FI.farmerId AND W.produceId = PN.produceId AND W.produceId =?";

/* assuming cropId is a string given your quotes in the original */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $cropId);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I'll upgrade my script once I get this issue sorted out

Comment: Making the change may get "this issue sorted out."

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but it looks like you're passing the `clicked_id` of the element, and not the *value* of that element.  Try this from your jQuery code:

```
function cropDescrip(clicked_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url : "../php/cropdescrip.php",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : 'JSON',
    cache : false,
    data : {cropId : $("#" + clicked_id).val()},  // <-- HERE
    success : function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    } //end success
  }); //end ajax
} //end cropDescrip
```

This will find the element with the id, using `element_id` as the selector value.  It will capture the value of that element, and pass it through the `cropId` key to the PHP server.

If this doesn't work as-is, it would be very useful to know precisely what `clicked_id` actually is (show the HTML and Javascript code for it), and what value is being passed to the PHP server in `$_POST[cropId]`.

Comment: @micheal... clicked_id is the id of a button.  An echo statement of $cropId shows that the id value is being passed to the php script via $_POST.  is_string($cropId) returns true

Comment: For some reason the $cropId is not being passed to the query statement

Comment: @ChrisJ When I asked for "precisely", I mean the exact code, including id and value, as well as a capture of the actual values being received by the server.  It's going to be virtually impossible to debug this through dialogue.  I can help, but I need to see exactly what is happening on both sides.  Please add this information to your Question - you can use the `edit` button below the question (above the comments) to add new information to the question.

Comment: Solved the problem... I had to redo how I was sending the button's id when I clicked the button.... Now I can do as ghenghy suggested and use prepared statements